# I am trying to send data through postman but the post method sends nothing

Tags: php, postman

$_POST Method Returns no data from postman.

```
//print_r($POST['Mobile']); (Prints nothing)

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

$response = array();

print_r($_POST['Mobile']);

if ($db->updateCart(
    $_POST['CartData'],
    $_POST['Mobile']
    )) {
    $response['error'] = false;
    $response['message'] = "positive";
}else{
    $response['error'] = true;
    $response['message'] = "Negative";
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

}

I've tried printing "something" in the print_r and it works fine.
can anyone please tell where am i doing wrong.

Below is the Postman Image i am trying to send.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the **Params** tab, try going to **Body** and selecting `form-data`, and entering your key/value pairs there.

I don't think this has anything to do with PHP. The issue appears to be that the Params tab sends your data as `GET` params rather than `POST` data. I'd bet that if you `print_r($_GET)` you'd see the data you were expecting to see in `$_POST`.

### Edit: using both Params and Body

It's possible to pass settings in both places. Consider:

```php
<?php
/* index.php */
print_r([
  '$_GET' => $_GET,
  '$_POST' => $_POST,
]);
```

And in Postman, just do this:

[image]

Note that the vars in Params are in the query string.

Comment: What If i want to use Params because i am trying to send data from android app which uses params. is there anyway?

Answer (score 1):

use the following to receive the data

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Post fields should be sent through request body, not through query string ( when you can expect to receieve them through get request). In postman, switch to body tab, select raw format and content type JSON, and place this in body:

```
{

"CartData" : "some data", 
"Mobile" : "123456789"

 }
```